# Determine if O/S is Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-vista, windows-xp, version

Working on a project and need to be able to determine whether the O/S is Windows 7, Vista or default to XP. I understand I could run into Win2K and earlier versions but let's just say that's not a concern as other code will catch that before it gets to this point. My application will be in C++ for the time being using VS2005. I've found articles and sample code alike but they seem way bloated for my uses. Just looking for a quick and dirty return.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724358%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 20, accepted):

List of [Windows Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724832(VS.85).aspx), using [`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451(VS.85).aspx):

```
Version Number    Description
6.1               Windows 7     / Windows 2008 R2
6.0               Windows Vista / Windows 2008
5.2               Windows 2003 
5.1               Windows XP
5.0               Windows 2000
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not distinguish between the recent Workstation and Server platforms. See: http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=10476

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions for an up-to-date list. You can also test osvi.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION for "normal" vs "Server" versions of Windows: i.e. 6.1 is Windows 7 (true) or Windows Server 2008 R2 (false).

Answer (score 19):

In general, you don't want to be testing against a specific version number, but rather checking for a particular feature. If you really want to detect "Windows 7 or later," however...

```
#include <windows.h>

bool IsWin7OrLater() {
    DWORD version = GetVersion();
    DWORD major = (DWORD) (LOBYTE(LOWORD(version)));
    DWORD minor = (DWORD) (HIBYTE(LOWORD(version)));

    return (major > 6) || ((major == 6) && (minor >= 1));
}
```

For 2000, compare major and minor against 5 and 0, respectively. For XP, compare against 5 and 1. For Vista, 6 and 0.

Answer (score 5):

The Windows 8.1 SDK<sup>1)</sup> introduced a number of [Version Helper functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972.aspx), that help determine the version of the OS an application is running on:

```
#include <VersionHelpers.h>

...

    if ( IsWindows7OrGreater() ) {
        // Windows 7 or above
    } else if ( IsWindowsVistaOrGreater() ) {
        // Windows Vista
    } else if ( IsWindowsXPOrGreater() ) {
        // Windows XP
    } else {
        // Unsupported version of Windows
    }
```

If you need to distinguish between client and server editions of Windows, you can call [IsWindowsServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424963.aspx).

---

<sup>1)</sup> *The Windows 8.1 SDK can be used to build applications for all supported versions of Windows.*

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you can use [`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find the Windows version. A safer way would perhaps be to use [`VerifyVersionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725492%28VS.85%29.aspx). There are C examples for both [`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724429%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [`VerifyVersionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725491%28VS.85%29.aspx).

However, as repeatedly stated on MSDN [checking for the operating system version is usually not the best way of determining whether a particular feature is present](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724832%28VS.85%29.aspx).